# Check an object constructor

Tags: python, arrays, jinja2

I'm developing a Flask-Python app and I'd like to know how do I get an object class/constructor.

I want this because I had to merge two different arrays and now I have a **result** array with objects of both classes.

Imagine this:

```
[Person, Person, Person, Person]
[Pet, Pet, Pet, Pet, Pet]
```

I merged both arrays in birthdate order and I have a final array:

```
[Person, Pet, Pet, Person, Pet, Pet, Person]
```

But now I want to print them on my **PetPerson.html**. How do I differentiate both of them if the variable for **birthdate** is different?

```
{% for a in personpets %}
if this object is a pet:
print a.petbirthdate
else:
print a.personbirthdate
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to know which class the object belongs to.

You can check that using `object_name.__class__.__name__`, this will give you either `Person` or `Pet` in this case. And hence you can replace this in your if condition as.

`{% for a in personpets %}
if object.__class__.__name__ == "Pet":
print a.petbirthdate
else:
print a.personbirthdate
{% endblock %}`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use inherit.

Let's say both person and pets are animals:

```
class Animals(object):
    get_birthdate(self):pass
```

Then your person and pet inherit from animals:

```
class Person(Animal):
get_birthdate(self):
    return self.personbirthdate

class Pet(Animal):
    get_birthdate(self):
        return self.petbirthdate
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for a in personpets %}
{{ a.get_birthdate }}
{% endblock %}
```